# Yii2: has_many gridview and detailview

Tags: php, yii2

I'm going to use 1st normalization form in my Yii2 project, so I've added table like this 
**| id | post_id | tag_id |**
and when I'm to posts model I've writed this:

```
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostTags::className(), ['post_id' => 'id']);
}
```

In view widget I've added 'tags.tag_id', but it shows no data.
Is there any way to show this tags in **DetailView** and **GridView** widgets?

May be, I can write "group_concat" somewhere?

Comment: I've found the problem. I didn't added **joinWith** to DataProvider query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to write a widget for displaying a links list of related records. It's reusable, prevents HTML generation in model / controller, reduces the amount of code in view.

```
<?php

namespace common\widgets;

use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;

/**
 * Widget for display list of links to related models
 */
class RelatedList extends Widget
{
    /**
     * @var \yii\db\ActiveRecord[] Related models
     */
    public $models = [];

    /**
     * @var string Base to build text content of the link.
     * You should specify attribute name. In case of dynamic generation ('getFullName()') you should specify just 'fullName'.
     */
    public $linkContentBase = 'name';

    /**
     * @var string Route to build url to related model
     */
    public $viewRoute;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if (!$this->models) {
            return null;
        }

        $items = [];
        foreach ($this->models as $model) {
            $items[] = Html::a($model->{$this->linkContentBase}, [$this->viewRoute, 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return Html::ul($items, [
            'class' => 'list-unstyled',
            'encode' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here are some examples (assuming tag name is stored in `name` column).

Usage in `GridView`:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'tags',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        /* @var $model common\models\Post */
        return RelatedList::widget([
            'models' => $model->tags,
            'viewRoute' => '/tags/view',
        ]);
    },
],
```

Usage in `DetailView`:

```
/* @var $model common\models\Post */

...

[
    'attribute' => 'tags',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => RelatedList::widget([
        'models' => $model->tags,
        'viewRoute' => '/tags/view',
    ]),        
],
```

Don't forget to set format `raw`, because by default content is rendered as plain text to prevent XSS attacks (html special characters are escaped).

You can modify this to fit your needs, this is just an example.

Comment: problem is that I need something like "tags.id". When I use hasOne relation, I just need to write "tags.id" and it shows only 1st selected element, but if I use several id's, it doesn't work